# Parsing string of array of array of string back to array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, node.js

I have an array of arrays of strings saved in a database column as a varchar:

```
[["ben"],["john","mike"],["ben"]]
```

I want to parse the data back into an array of arrays, so I can show the data on the screen. While attempting to do this, I ran into an awkward and annoying problem:

Here's the JSON response that is generated on the server and sent back to the client:

```
var response = "[{\"Names\":\""+ rows[i].Names + "\"}]";
res.send(response);
```

Here's the client code I wrote to parse the data:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: ...,
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
}).done(function(data) {
  jQuery.each(JSON.parse(data), function(i, parsedData) {
    var names = JSON.parse(parsedData.Names);
    var labels = "";
    for (var n = 0; n < names.length; n++) {
      var label = "<label>" + names[n] + "</label>";
      labels = labels + label;
    }
    console.log(labels);
  });
});
```

This is the error i'm getting:

[image]

Here's the JSON validation:

[image]

How can I solve this?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you're attempting to achieve here, however you're calling `JSON.stringify()` on content that's already a string.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i want to get the array of arrays from the database as a string and parse it back to an array of arrays. I've edited my question and deleted the stringify function, however it is still not working

Comment: That array of array doesn't look like valid JSON

Comment: @Laazo i've added the JSON validation

Comment: I believe you need to escape the quotes in your DB column's value for this to parse correctly

Comment: can you post the content of `data` ? before you send it to `jQuery.each(JSON.parse(data)...`

Comment: _“Here's the JSON response that is generated on the server and sent back to the client”_ - why are you creating JSON “manually”? You should really rather populate the correct _data structures_, and then use the method the language provides to create JSON from that.

Comment: Pretty sure the “JSON” string you are creating here eventually ends up being `[{"Names":"[["ben"],["john","mike"],["ben"]]"}]`, and that is _not_ valid JSON. I think you actually want `response = "[{\"Names\":"+ rows[i].Names + "}]";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a simple rule:

**Never use string tools to create or modify JSON. No string concatenation (`+`), no string replace and God forbid no regex.**

The only way to produce JSON is to use a JSON serializer on a data structure. And the only way to manipulate JSON is to parse it, modify the data structure, and then serialize it again. JSON itself is to be treated as a constant, for all intents and purposes.

Your server code violates that rule. Change it like this:

```
var responseData = [{
    Names: rows[i].Names
}];

var response = JSON.stringify(responseData);
```

In the above, `responseData` is a data structure. You are free to modify it. `response` is derived from that. You are **not** free to modify it, the only thing you can do with `response` is to write it to the client.

Note that `rows[i].Names` might be JSON itself, so you end up with a double-encoded value in your response.

Provided the server sends the `Content-Type: application/json` header, the client can use this:

```
jQuery.get("...").done(function(data) {
  // data is already parsed here, you don't need to parse it

  jQuery.each(data, function(i, item) {
    // item.Names is not yet (!) parsed here, so we need to parse it
    var names = JSON.parse(item.Names);

    var labels = names.map(function (name) {
      return $("<label>", {text: name});
    }

    console.log( labels );
  });
});
```

If you don't want to call `JSON.parse()` on the client, you have to call it on the server:

```
var responseData = [{
    Names: JSON.parse(rows[i].Names)
}];

var response = JSON.stringify(responseData);
```

Comment: Thank you, the changes you suggested worked perfectly!

Comment: Tanks for the feedback!